# How much information a Flash program (Flash app) can gather about computer when running?

Tags: flash

Does anyone know if a flash web application has access to local hard drive? What about OS information or hardware information?

If I allow webcam and microphone access, how much information can it get about hardware, os and computer?

I'm asking because I'm worried how much information can 3rd party sites gather when I allow running flash applications.

Answer (score 0):

Flash web apps can access certain information about the device running the browser. If you have a look at the AS3 Capabilities class you will get an idea of what's possible: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/system/Capabilities.html ... I don't believe you can get any intrusive data from Flash web apps though.